# need to disable input for bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker, bootstrap-timepicker

I am using Bootstrap time-picker. I have successfully implemented it. But what I need is user is only able to insert in 30 min gap like: 10:00,10:30,11:00 etc. For that I have tried is `minuteStep` as shown below, and it works perfect.

```
 $('#fantasyleague-draft_time').timepicker({
     template: false,
     showInputs: false,
     minuteStep: 30
 });
```

But what is the issue is user can type time as he need. So, how to prevent it to enter time manually?

For this I have refer [bootstrap timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/)

Comment: after fiddling a while with the  Bootstrap time-picker i came to the conclusion that you might have to do a hack with the Bootstrap time-picker js code to get it working the way you intended. Anyway Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i have done so far now is :

```
<input type="text" id="fantasyleague-draft_time" readonly>
```

Added CSS

```
fantasyleague-draft_time{cursor: pointer;}
```

and JS:

```
 $('#fantasyleague-draft_time').timepicker({
     template: false,
     showInputs: false,
     minuteStep: 30
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in your text box :->

```
<input type="text" id="fantasyleague-draft_time" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<input type="text" disabled>`..it will not allow to do anything..after 30 min remove `disabled` attribute using javascript or jquery

Comment: no dear this is not right approch. i am finding some relavent

Comment: you don't want to allow user to add anything in input right?

Comment: yes, but this datepicker has feature that we can up/down its time.

Comment: yah now got it..let me try now :)

Comment: set  hour-step and minute-step to zero and readonly-input="true" it will completely disable timepicker @IshanShah

Comment: if i will do minute-step 0 then it will not do of 30 min gap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99461/discussion-between-ishan-shah-and-debin).

Comment: How to remove the disabled from the picker?