# Bootstrap time picker disable alphabets entering

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to disable alphabet entering in Bootstrap time Picker.

My time Picker code is:

```
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <input
    id="timepicker4"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="startingTime"
    value="00:00"
    required
  />
</div>
```

And Jquery Calling function is:

```
jQuery('#timepicker4').timepicker({showMeridian: false}).
```

What can I do? But i dont need to disable Input i only need dont type alphabets..

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: which bootstrap are you using. can  u send the link

Comment: Bootstarp link is: https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/graphs/contributors

Comment: i dont need date, i only need time@ Alexis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [need to disable input for bootstrap timepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555563/need-to-disable-input-for-bootstrap-timepicker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the showInput false, then display time in span tag

```
showInputs : false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this many way.

**First way to do:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awkbng0w/23/)
**Second way to do:**  [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satfyafj/)

You can use `onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"` in your input field.

```js
jQuery('#timepicker4').timepicker({
  showMeridian: false
})
```

```html
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <input id="timepicker4" type="text" class="form-control" name="startingTime" value="00:00" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" required/>
</div>
```